# Does every instance creates a new method, which is defined in a constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop

Given Constructor

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.greeting = function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.');
  };
}
```

We create two instances. e.g.

```
var person1 = new Person('Bob');
var person2 = new Person('Sarah');
```

How many greeting methods gets created with every instance?

Comment: 1 for each instance

Comment: There'll be a new Function instance per object, but the code will be shared by all of them so it's not really a big deal unless you're creating millions of them.

Comment: If greeting was declared as `Person.prototype.greeting = function()...` then there would only be 1 across all instances

Comment: Yes, it does :(

Comment: So, Prototype is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Only one greeting method gets created per object because you only have one method in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There will be one function, but there are as many closures as you create persons. As javascript is working a lot with closures there is not much overhead and that should usually not be a problem. But if you are creating millions of them it might be better to just move them to the prototype, then there will be only one closure.

Answer (score 0):

Every person will have one `greeting()` method (Also called: 'Member function').

e.g.

```
person1.greeting(); #Output: 'Hi I'm Bob.'
person2.greeting(); #Output: 'Hi I'm Sarah.'
```